# Can not download 12.10

Tags: 12.10, downloads, iso

I do not know what might be the cause of this but I can't download Ubuntu 12.10 from their website, it gets stuck on 761 MB.

I disabled avp system and tried to download it with Chrome and Firefox but still it got stuck on 761MB out of 763MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantal Quetzal 12.10 has just been released.  The servers are extremely busy.  Added to this, a large number of updates for Quantal have just dropped.

I suggest you try a [BitTorrent download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads).

I've been getting my iso images through the official bitTorrent for a few years now, for several reasons:

1. Packets are fully verified and fixed if faulty.  I haven't had a bad md5sum since I started using this method (had a couple of expensive dud downloads prior to that though)
2. It's quicker than downloading directly at times like this, when many thousands of people are all trying to get a new release.
3. Nothing can completely ruin the download.  As soon as you start your BitTorrent client (eg Transmission) the download will continue where it left off. Poor or slow internet connections cannot ruin your download competely

Comment: Thank you for the reply 
Isn't it illegal ?? and i think i have good internet is 50Mb per second good or not

Comment: The torrent links on that page are the official ones, there's nothing illegal about it.  You *can* use torrents to download copyrighted material such as movies or commercial software and of course this contravenes the copyright laws in all but a few countries.  There's nothing illegal about using the technology itself for legitimate purposes however.

Comment: A 50 megabit per second link would download the Ubuntu iso in much less than 2 minutes (*about* 6.2+ Megabytes per second) so yes, it would be very good.  You may or may not see torrent speeds that quick, but at least you'll get the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to download it by Torrent system, or choose another mirror.
If you prefer the direct download, I recommend to use a download manager (Uget, Steadyflow), so you can pause it.

There is a list of mirrors and torrent links on this site:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads